# What's meant by this measure in the sample space of a probability distribution?

Tags: information-geometry

In Amari's "Information Geometry and its Applications", in section 2.1 they define the exponential family as

$$ p(x, \pmb\theta) = \exp \{ \theta^i h_i (x) + k(x) - \psi (\pmb\theta) \}$$

(where the $\theta^i h_i$ uses Einstein summation), and then say

> We introduce a new vector random variable $x = (x_1 , . . . , x_n )$ by $x_i = h_i (x)$

and

> We further introduce a measure in the sample space $X = \{\pmb x\}$ by $d\mu(\pmb x) = \exp \{k(x)\} dx$

This lets them rewrite $p$ as

$$p(x, \pmb \theta)d x = \exp \{\pmb \theta \cdot \pmb x − \psi(\pmb \theta)\} d\mu(\pmb x)$$

This is just substitution of the above and makes sense to me. But they go further and write:

$$p(\pmb x, \pmb \theta) = \exp \{\pmb \theta \cdot \pmb x − \psi(\pmb \theta)\}$$

(note boldface $\pmb x$ here.)

I'm confused about several points, but most of all by what the measure $d\mu(\pmb x)$ is. What's the significance of it, and why introduce it? I've read the Wikipedia article for probability measures but I still don't get it.

Further, how do they go from the 2nd form of $p$ above to the last one?

Comment: The measure $d\mu(x)$ simply is a measure with Lebesgue density $e^{k(x)}$.

Comment: Regarding the meaning of the measure $d\mu(x)$: this is part of the standard definition of the exponential family, for example it appears via the density $h(x)$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family . Sometimes it is called the "carrier measure" in the literature on the exponential family.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a measure $\mu$ by
$$
d\mu(\pmb x) = \exp \{k(x)\} dx
$$
means
$$
\mu(E) = \int_E \exp \{k(x)\} dx
$$
for sets $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, or equivalently
$$
\int F(\pmb x)\;d\mu(\pmb x) = \int F(\pmb x)\exp \{k(x)\}\; dx
$$
for functions $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.   So, in this case
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} F(\pmb x)\;d\mu(\pmb x) = \int_{\mathbb R} F\big(h_1(x),\dots,h_n(x)\big)\exp \{k(x)\}\; dx
$$

---

Like you, I cannot understand the "they go further" part.

---

Another remark.  It seems they use a summation conventon, whereby
$\theta^i h_i (x)$ means $\sum_{i=1}^n \theta^i h_i (x)$